# Cordova Plugins already defined

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I am facing "**Plugins already defined**" and "d**eviceready has not fired after 5 seconds**" errors in cordova angular project.

I am using

- Cordova Version: 6.3.1
- android 5.2.2
- ios 4.2.1

[image: Detailed Error:]

I tried to remove and adding android platform again.
Injecting cordova.js only once.
Cordova.js file is loading.

Thank You.

Comment: remove **cordova_plugins.js** from index.html and try again

Comment: Thanks @Naitik I am not using cordova_plugins in index.html.

Comment: try to add **http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"** in your meta tag

Comment: @Naitik <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" /> is already there in index.html

Comment: set the Content Security Policy default-src property 
from 
"**default-src 'self' http: https:;**" 
to 
"**default-src * ;**"

Comment: and if you are using file plugin in your project please upgrade it

Comment: @Naitik Tried with above change. It is throwing lot of errors now.

1) The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'style-src' contains an invalid source: 'http://'. It will be ignored.
index.html:22 The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: 'http://'. It will be ignored.

2) Refused to load the font bla bla

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125574/discussion-between-naitik-and-vishal-rajole).